# Variable becomes empty inside scope loop (Octobercms)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, octobercms

I have `$slug` variable that takes frontend url slug value and sends it to model scope. Inside scope if I use `echo $slug` it works and also it works inside query (I have it to display products that have only same category slug).

Query where `$slug` works:

```
return $query->orwhereHas('category', function($q) use ($slug){
  $q->where('slug', '=', $slug);
})->paginate($perPage, $page);
```

Here is the SQL:

```
select * from `slasher_farming_mods` where exists (select * from `slasher_farming_categories` where `slasher_farming_mods`.`category_id` = `slasher_farming_categories`.`id` and `slug` = 'medium-tractors') limit 4 offset 0
```

As visible slug value is "medium-tractors".

If I try to use $slug inside sort loop or inside brands loop it becomes empty

```
public function scopeListFrontEnd($query, $options = [], $slug = ''){
        extract(array_merge([
            'page' => 1,
            'perPage' => 4,
            'sort' => 'brandName desc',
            'brands' => null,
            'categorySlug' => null,
        ], $options));


    print $slug; //This works here

    if(!is_array($sort)) {
        $sort = [$sort];
    }


    foreach ($sort as $_sort){
        if(in_array($_sort, array_keys(self::$allowedSortingOptions))){
            $parts = explode(' ', $_sort);

            if(count($parts) < 2){
                array_push($parts, 'desc');
            }

            list($sortField, $sortDirection) = $parts;
            $query->orderBy($sortField, $sortDirection);
        }
    }

    if($brands !== null) {
        if(!is_array($brands)){
            $brands = [$brands];
        }

        foreach ($brands as $brand){
            $query->orwhereHas('brand', function($q) use ($brand){
                $q->where('brand_id', '=', $brand);
            });
        }
    }

    $lastPage = $query->paginate($perPage, $page)->lastPage();


    if($lastPage < $page) {
        $page = 1;
    }

    return $query->orwhereHas('category', function($q) use ($slug){
        $q->where('slug', '=', $slug);
    })->paginate($perPage, $page);

}
```

Example SQL when using brands filter

```
select * from `slasher_farming_mods` where exists (select * from `slasher_farming_brands` where `slasher_farming_mods`.`brand_id` = `slasher_farming_brands`.`id` and `brand_id` = '5') or exists (select * from `slasher_farming_categories` where `slasher_farming_mods`.`category_id` = `slasher_farming_categories`.`id` and `slug` = '') order by `name` desc limit 4 offset 0
```

Slug variable becomes empty.

How could I keep slug variable data inside brand loop or inside sort loop?

Comment: from where you are assigning data to slug?

Comment: From frontend twig file inside PHP section I have onStart function. And then pass it like this $this['mods'] = Mods::listFrontEnd($options, $slug);

Comment: @Basharmal or is there Any easier way to get page url slug inside model?

Comment: What is the output of $slug inside the `orwhereHas` statement? You can use `traceLog()` or `trace_log()` functions to write to system.log instead of `print` statement